# System.IndexOutOfRangeException in ThreadContext - a .NET bug? Workarounds?

Tags: c#

I have run into exception, which seems to happen rarely, but not in repeatable conditions. Here's stack trace:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.ProcessFilters(MSG& msg, Boolean& modified)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
```

An application is using its own MessageFilter, unfortunately I cannot post source code, but by stack trace alone it doesn't seem like it would help a lot, also additional search revealed that ([source](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000054798?l=en_US&pg=kbase&fs=KnowledgeBase&pn=1), apparently related to another application, where such exception happened):

> This is caused by a Microsoft bug in the .Net runtime event loop.  The
>   problem relates to how the runtime processes internal event message
>   filters that are registered by the application.  The index referred to
>   in the message is an index used to process the message filters when
>   the application is exiting.  But in this particular Microsoft bug the
>   message filter references are no longer valid.

Question is: are there any workarounds to that specific issue?

Comment: To further enlighten readers, could you post the url of the resource where you got "This is caused by a Microsoft bug in the .Net runtime event loop." from?

Comment: In the link you posted, it says `Workaround: To work around the problem remove the PROCESS EVENTS statement from the code that closes the windows.`.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez this is apparently application specific workaround though.